# What is the default username and password for s390x?

Tags: login, password, cloud

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 cloud image for s390x, but I couldn't login after it starts as I don't know the root password.

I downloaded the s390x ubuntu 18.04 image from [this site](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release/), but after the qemu VM starts, I couldn't login to the VM: root password not known.

Comment: As stated [at the bottom of this document](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart-s390x), the username and password are both `ubuntu` 

Comment: I am using the disk img ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-s390x.img

Comment: And tried ubuntu/ubuntu, not working

Answer (score 0):

The default username is `ubuntu` and the default password is `ubuntu`.

For security, you should change your password the first time you log in.

Comment: I tried the "ubuntu"/"ubuntu", but it doesn't allow me to login: ubuntu login: ubuntu
Password:

Login incorrect